# reStructuredText Bibliographic fields proper usage

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, bibliography

What is the proper way to use the [reStructuredText Bibliographic fields](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#bibliographic-fields) for a python file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most prominent example of how to use such fields is in the Python PEPs, e.g. [PEP-0414](http://hg.python.org/peps/file/tip/pep-0414.txt):

```
PEP: 414
Title: Explicit Unicode Literal for Python 3.3
Version: $Revision$
Last-Modified: $Date$
Author: Armin Ronacher <armin.ronacher@active-4.com>,
        Nick Coghlan <ncoghlan@gmail.com>
Status: Final
Type: Standards Track
Content-Type: text/x-rst
Created: 15-Feb-2012
Post-History: 28-Feb-2012, 04-Mar-2012
Resolution: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-February/116995.html
```

While this is a longish list of fields, it shows how they are used.

As explained in the reST documentation,

> This bibliographic data corresponds to the front matter of a book, such as the title page and copyright page.

so there should be only one set of such fields per document, namely at the beginning. Don't forget that reST was developed as a lightweight markup for Python documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Mind, that the PEP source accepts a special syntax variant. In standard rST,
the "field-list" syntax with enclosing colons must be used:

```
:Content-Type: text/x-rst
:Created: yesterday
:Abstract: This is just a silly example
```

See the [Docutils documentation](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs)
for more examples. (Also check the rST source files that are linked on every documentation page.)